# How do I fix laggy UITableView scrolling performance when downloading JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, multithreading, uitableview

In my application, I download a JSON file off of the internet and fill up a UITableView with items from the file. It does work well, and there are no problems or errors, but the scrolling performance is very laggy, and the UI glitches out a tiny bit.

I assume this is because of the images that I'm downloading from the JSON file, so I've looked into multi-threading, but I don't think I am doing it right because it *does* load much faster, but scrolling performance is still the same as before.

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this? This UITableView is the most important thing in the app, and I have been spending much time on trying to fix it. Thank you!

Here is my code-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var nameArray = [String]()
var idArray = [String]()
var ageArray = [String]()
var genderArray = [String]()
var descriptionArray = [String]()
var imgURLArray = [String]()

let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

final let urlString = "https://pbsocfilestorage.000webhostapp.com/jsonDogs.json"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.downloadJsonWithURL()

    // Activity Indicator
    myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
    myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) ->
        Void in
        print("Good so far...")
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "dogs"))

            if let dogArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "dogs") as? NSArray {
                print("Why u no work!")
                for dog in dogArray {

                    if let dogDict = dog as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.nameArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "id") {
                            self.idArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "age") {
                            self.ageArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "gender") {
                            self.genderArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "image") {
                                self.imgURLArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = dogDict.value(forKey: "description") {
                            self.descriptionArray.append(name as! String)
                        }

                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }).resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLArray[indexPath.row])
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell") as! TableViewCell

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (imgURL as! URL), completionHandler: {(data, resp, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil && data != nil) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                cell.dogNameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.idLabel.text = self.idArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.ageLabel.text = self.ageArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.genderLabel.text = self.genderArray[indexPath.row]
                print("Cell info was filled in!")

                if imgURL != nil {
                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as? URL)!)
                    cell.dogImage.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
                }
            })
        }
    }).resume()

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDog" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let detailViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            detailViewController.imageString = imgURLArray[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.nameString = nameArray[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.idString = idArray[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.ageString = ageArray[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.descriptionString = descriptionArray[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.genderString = genderArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In addition to the accepted response from @vadian, you may want to specify a `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` in you `viewDidLoad` and set the `tableView.rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big mistake. You are loading data with `dataTask` but you aren't using that returned data at all. Rather than you are loading the data a second time with synchronous `contentsOf`. Don't do that.

And don't update the labels in the asynchronous completion block. The strings are not related to the image data.

This is more efficient:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let imgURL = URL(string: imgURLArray[indexPath.row])
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.dogNameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.idLabel.text = self.idArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.ageLabel.text = self.ageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.genderLabel.text = self.genderArray[indexPath.row]
    print("Cell info was filled in!")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imgURL!) { (data, resp, error) in

        if let data = data {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                cell.dogImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            })
        }
    }.resume()

    return cell
}
```

Note: You are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. It's very error-prone. Use a custom struct or class. And create `imgURLArray` with `URL` instances rather than strings. This is also much more efficient.

Nevertheless, you should use a download manager which caches the images and cancels downloads if a cell goes off-screen. At the moment each image is downloaded again when the user scrolls and `cellForRow` is called again for this particular cell.

Comment: Thank you! The scrolling is _finally_ smooth! I was following a tutorial for downloading the JSON into the TableView, and I guess it wasn't very good. I will take your notes into account.